# Trouble connecting with sql-server database

Tags: sql-server, alfresco, jtds

I am trying to connect Alfresco Community 4.0 (installed in Tomcat7) with SQL Server 2012 but I keep having the same problem "Connection Refused". With mysql, everything worked fine.

I already turned the firewall off and enabled TCP/IP. The SQL Server Service is also running so I cannot figure out what the problem is. My driver is also working because I have another application (orbeon) using it.

Do you have any idea of what is happening? My configurations are the following:

```
db.name=alfresco
db.username=alfresco
db.password=alfresco
db.host=127.0.0.1
db.port=1433
db.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://${db.host}:${db.port}/${db.name}
db.txn.isolation=4096
```

My error is:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:215)
```

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix this :

```
db.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://${db.host}:${db.port}/${db.name}
```

Do it something like the following;

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DAN-Aladino-vs.usersad.everis.int:1433/AladinoSFA2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the access permissions to the user to access the table.

here Database name is "alfresco".

So, You can find security --> Logins -->List of users. right click on user "alfresco" and go to properties.In this you will find user mapping.Now you need to enable access right's to alfersco i.e user to that particular database.

Try this...

Comment: I have a Login named "alfresco" that is dbowner. When I connect the user "alfresco" to the database "alfresco" I have permissions to do everything in that database.